# Cannot connect Locally to ElasticCache cluster on aws using Jedis Lib

Tags: java, redis, local, nat, jedis

We are trying to access de ElasticCache (Redis) on aws using a Java client that runs locally using Jedis lib. We were able to access the redis using redis-cli locally following the steps [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html).

The problem is that when we try to connect to aws Redis using Jedis lib, the NAT public address are being translated to the redis private IPs in order to calculate the slots (initializeSlotsCache). We couldn't find a way to disable this. Are there any workaround?

Here's how we connect using Jedis:

```
    factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisClusterConfiguration(this.clusterProperties.getNodes()));
    factory.setUsePool(true);
    factory.setPoolConfig(this.jedisPoolConfig());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory;
```

We are using the mapped NAT ips for each node. But the Jedis lib is saving the private ips in the cache, so we get the following exception:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Any suggestions would be great! We are running out of options. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to AWS hosted redis from outside the AWS environment.

We had faced a similar issue, and the work around we had was to install a local redis instance for dev and unit testing.